# Yes / No control of Time Machine

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

In the preferences of Time Machine, there is a Yes / No control on the left of the panel. I would like to implement such a control but I didn't find it in IB. Is there a way to implement this control without having to write custom code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no similar control in IB.

But easiest way to create ON/OFF switch is use segmented control:

[image]

And little bit more code is needed if you want "exact same" control.

[image]

There is button inside box object and some code is needed to move that button from left to right.